# Intellij Idea selection to ideavim selection

Tags: ideavim

For example, if I select text with my mouse and then press "y" ideavim successfully copy it to its buffer. But if I make selection with intellij "extend selection" command (`map <leader>w :action EditorSelectWord<CR>`) I cannot do anything with this selection with ideavim. Maybe there is shortcut for this? I know such feature is in vim plugin for NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

In the feature request that Andrey linked ( [VIM-510](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-510) ), someone mentions that if you first put yourself in visual mode (pressing v) that you can then use those actions and still get you expected behavior with d, y, etc.

What I'm trying to do now, is have a mapping with w put me into visual mode if coming from normal mode and do the selection, otherwise if I'm already in visual mode, to just do the selection. It seems like this should work, but unfortunately, I can't seem to get the remapping correct in my .ideavimrc to do that.

```
nnoremap <leader>w v:action EditorSelectWord<CR>
vnoremap <leader>w :action EditorSelectWord<CR>
```

^ That doesn't seem to work for me right now.  :(

Answer (score 1):

IdeaVim cannot work with Select Word at Caret selections. Feel free to vote for the feature request [VIM-510](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-510) in order to track its status.